# What Database, and In Which Setup Can handle Several Millions Inserts Per Minute?

Tags: database, nosql, data-warehouse

We have come to a point where for few of our customers' systems, at peak times, events are generated at that crazy rate. That is, millions of new events per minute (between 1M and 2M).

The records/docs size are 1.5Kb on average.

Is there a database that can handles such radical writing speed out there (16K - 32K Inserts per second)?

There are several candidates out there, Cassandra, Hive, Hadoop, HBase, Riak and perhaps few others, but I am willing to know from someone's else *experience* and not just quoting from each db-system's website self testimonials.

If you have handled such load at your work, your advise is highly appreciated.

Comment: This might be better on dba.stackexchange.

Comment: didn't know about dba.se. thanks. moving forward...

Comment: I just found out about it when I flagged it for migration.  This question seems on topic for that site.

Comment: The question is much to broad. Are these events batched up, or individual "inserts"? What is the data to be used for? A nosql solution might give you very fast writes, but good luck aggregating the result sets...

Comment: @NWest I currently use insert-many option in mongo every few seconds, adding all accumulated data in between.

Answer (score 1):

[Couchbase](http://www.couchbase.com/) can easily handle that write speed. Not sure what budget you have (what size machines you will look at), but getting a trio of m3.2xl's can easily do 80K/s and still have replication for redundancy and failover. Of course, configuring with raid0 multiple ebs volumes and provisioned IOPS will keep things humming.

Of course I would ask more questions about it if we get more specific, like how much of that is working set that needs read access, etc. which can help tune the solution.

Comment: if you have questions you can ping me on twitter -- @scalabl3

Comment: I will definitely give it a try, almost got CouchDB and CouchBase mixed up in mind ;-).. Also seeing your blog is full of Couchbase info.

Comment: Yeah, Couchbase is a different product (and is a company) which evolved from memcached -> Membase => Couchbase. The founders of CouchDB left the Apache project and merged with Membase to make Couchbase several years ago.